# python pandas - select particular values after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have groupby table:

```
df.groupby(['Age', 'Movie']).mean()

                  User  Raitings
Age Movie
1   1         4.666667  7.666667
    2         4.666667  8.000000
    3         2.000000  7.500000
    4         2.000000  5.500000
    5         3.000000  7.000000
18  1         3.000000  7.500000
    2         3.000000  8.000000
    3         3.000000  8.500000
25  1         8.000000  7.250000
    2         8.000000  7.500000
    3         5.500000  8.500000
    4         5.000000  7.000000
45  1         9.000000  7.500000
    2         9.000000  7.500000
    3        11.000000  7.000000
    4        11.000000  6.000000
60  1         8.000000  7.000000
    2         8.000000  9.000000
    3         8.000000  7.000000
```

please, help with function, which takes integer (Age) and return Movie with MIN raitings in this Age-group. 
Example def(1) should return 4 (min Raitings in group Age(1) = 5.5, Movies(5.5) = 4)

I can get min Raiting:

```
df['Raitings'].min()
```

But i don't know - how to get raiting in particular group (Age)?

Comment: I don't understand how you get the 4

Comment: example: i have age 18, in this group min integer in column "Raitings" - 7.5, 
corresponding Movie - 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source multi-index DF:

```
In [221]: x
Out[221]:
                 User  Raitings
Age  Movie
1.0  1       4.666667  7.666667
     2       4.666667  8.000000
     3       2.000000  7.500000
     4       2.000000  5.500000
     5       3.000000  7.000000
18.0 1       3.000000  7.500000
     2       3.000000  8.000000
     3       3.000000  8.500000
25.0 1       8.000000  7.250000
     2       8.000000  7.500000
     3       5.500000  8.500000
     4       5.000000  7.000000
45.0 1       9.000000  7.500000
     2       9.000000  7.500000
     3      11.000000  7.000000
     4      11.000000  6.000000
60.0 1       8.000000  7.000000
     2       8.000000  9.000000
     3       8.000000  7.000000
```

Function:

```
In [222]: def f(df, age):
     ...:     return df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[age,:], 'Raitings'].idxmin()[1]
     ...:
```

Test:

```
In [223]: f(x, age=1)
Out[223]: 4
```

Comment: @VakarinDmitriy if it works, you can mark as The Answer, click the check mark left of the post (under the down arrow)

Comment: HI, how can we get both the columns say, 'user' & 'raitings' and when 'user' is string.?. In my case I have 'group' instead of 'age' which starts from '0'

Comment: @i1100362, i'd suggest you to open a new question with a small sample input data set and your desired data set... It's not very clear to me what do you want to get as an output. Are you after `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[1,:], :]` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661673/selecting-groups-fromed-by-groupby-function

Answer (score 4):

This gets all of them in one go.

```
df.groupby('Age').Raitings.idxmin().str[-1]

Age
1     4
18    1
25    4
45    4
60    1
Name: Raitings, dtype: int64
```

If you want a function, I'd use [**`pd.DataFrame.xs`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) (xs is for cross section).
By default, `xs` will grab from the first level of the index and subsequently drop that level.  This conveniently leaves the level in which we want to draw the value in which `idxmin` will hand us.

```
def f(df, age):
    return df.xs(age).Raitings.idxmin()

f(df, 1)

4
```

---

**Setup**
Useful for those who try to parse this stuff.

```
txt = """\
Age  Movie       User  Raitings
1.0  1       4.666667  7.666667
     2       4.666667  8.000000
     3       2.000000  7.500000
     4       2.000000  5.500000
     5       3.000000  7.000000
18.0 1       3.000000  7.500000
     2       3.000000  8.000000
     3       3.000000  8.500000
25.0 1       8.000000  7.250000
     2       8.000000  7.500000
     3       5.500000  8.500000
     4       5.000000  7.000000
45.0 1       9.000000  7.500000
     2       9.000000  7.500000
     3      11.000000  7.000000
     4      11.000000  6.000000
60.0 1       8.000000  7.000000
     2       8.000000  9.000000"""

df = pd.read_fwf(pd.io.common.StringIO(txt))
df = df.ffill(downcast='infer').set_index(['Age', 'Movie'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum for a specific age, you can do :

```
df["Age"==1]['Raitings'].min()
```

If you want to do it for the whole dataframe, you can do:

```
df.groupby("Age").agg({ "Raitings" : "min" })
```

I hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

I will reshape and do pivot. Think it will help

```
df.reset_index(inplace = true)
df_Min = pd.pivot_table(df,index = [‘Movie’, ‘User’], columns =‘Age’, values = ‘Raiting’, aggfunc = min )
```