# Selecting groups fromed by groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pandas-groupby

My dataframe:

```
 df1

group     ordercode      quantity
 0            A             1
              B             3
 1            C             1
              E             2
              D             1
```

I have formed each group by`groupby` function.

I need to extract the data by using group number.

My desired ouput.

In:get group 0
out:

```
   ordercode      quantity
       A             1
       B             3
```

or

```
 group     ordercode      quantity
 0            A             1
              B             3
```

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This answer might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691133/split-pandas-dataframe-based-on-groupby

Comment: `[df1.get_group(x) for x in df1.groups][0]` gives first group, `[df1.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups][1]' gives second group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), also is possible use parameter `drop_level=False`:

```
#if need remove original level

df1 = df.xs(0)
print (df1)
           quantity
ordercode          
A                 1
B                 3

#if avoid remove original level
df1 = df.xs(0, drop_level=False)
print (df1)
                 quantity
group ordercode          
0     A                 1
      B                 3
```

EDIT:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [x[x['group'] == 0] for x in dfs]
print (dfs)
```

Comment: when I use `df.xs` I get only `group ordercode          
0     A                 1
`

Comment: @i1100362 - Sorry, you need `df = df[df['group'] == 0]` ?

Comment: I just need to print group in a separate dataframe. Say I have 10 dataframesa and each has 100 gropus. Now in `new_df` I want to print the selective groups from each dataframe. So I need to know how to extract the group

Comment: @i1100362 - But why is necessary `groupby` ? I think here is not necessary, if need extract only group by filtering from comment above. Or something missing?

Comment: this is why I have formed groups https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475010/how-to-create-a-group-by-spliting-the-dataframe-using-python

Comment: @i1100362 - so need after `df['group'] = sorted(range(0, len(df)/3, 1) * 4)[0:len(df)]` ? Then `df = df[df['group'] == 0]` working fine.

Comment: this works fine. but what if I want to program in separate file?

Comment: @i1100362 - Separate file? Not sure if understand. Maybe is possible post your code from linked answer, or explain more?

Comment: Sorry. I am working in an excel file. By using Python3 I have created all these groups and saved in a separate file. now I am writing different program so I need to extract the data from my previously saved excel sheet. that's why I have posted this question. I have saved all data from the workbook in different dataframe and now I need to extract the data from each `df`

Comment: @i1100362 - are data confidental?

Comment: its not confidential but the file is huge.

Comment: So there is list of DataFrames extracted from excel files and need filter by `group` ? Then check edited answer.

Comment: Yes. but not checking the edited answers. I am writing a sequence (ex. production sequence)using group. which group I wanna produce first

Comment: @i1100362 - So `df = df[df['group'] == 0]` wotking for one DataFrame and need solution for multiple DataFrames?

Comment: Yes. for multiple dataframes

Comment: @i1100362 - and multiple dataframes are in list, dictionary or something else? How are stored?

Comment: Shall I post as a new question ??

Comment: @i1100362 - Sure, maybe also help  [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663926/selecting-data-from-multiple-dataframes

Answer (score 2):

```
In [131]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[0,:]]
Out[131]:
           quantity
ordercode
A                 1
B                 3
```

or

```
In [130]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[0,:], :]
Out[130]:
                 quantity
group ordercode
0.0   A                 1
      B                 3
```

Comment: I have tested this before , `typeerror:unhashable type:'slice'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GroupBy.get_group`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html) after specifying columns. Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
                   'B': np.random.rand(6),
                   'C': np.arange(6)})

gb = df.groupby('A')

print(gb[gb.obj.columns].get_group('bar'))

     A         B  C
1  bar  0.523248  1
3  bar  0.575946  3
5  bar  0.318569  5
```

Comment: I have the group. Now I want to access the data from the group. I have 10 data frames and each has 100 groups. so I want to select one group(using its group number) from each dataframe. So I need to know how to get particular group from my df

Comment: `I have formed the group already.` What does that mean exactly? To me, it just means you've done `gb = df.groupby('A')`. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for how you can improve your question.

Comment: yes. Now how can I get data from my group using group number

Comment: @i1100362, As in my answer, feed the key to `get_group`, e.g. `gb[gb.obj.columns].get_group(0)` if your key is `0`.