# Selecting data from multiple dataframes

Tags: python-3.x

my workbook  `Rule.xlsx` has following data.

sheet1:

```
 group      ordercode      quantity
     0            A             1
                  B             3
     1            C             1
                  E             2
                  D             1
```

Sheet 2:

```
group      ordercode      quantity
     0            x             1
                  y             3
     1            x             1
                  y             2
                  z             1
```

I have created dataframe using below method.

```
 df1 =data.parse('sheet1')
 df2=data.parse('sheet2')
```

my desired result is writing a sequence using these two dataframe.

```
 df3:

group      ordercode      quantity
     0            A             1
                  B             3
     0            x             1
                  y             3
     1            C             1
                  E             2
                  D             1
     1            x             1
                  y             2
                  z             1
```

one from df1 and one from df2.

I wish to know how I can print the data by selecting group number (eg. group(0), group(1) etc).

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some comments solution is:

```
#create OrderDict of DataFrames
dfs = pd.read_excel('Rule.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
#ordering of DataFrames
order = 'SWC_1380_81,SWC_1382,SWC_1390,SWC_1391,SWM_1380_81'.split(',')

#in loops lookup dictionaries, replace NaNs and create helper column
L = [dfs[x].ffill().assign(g=i) for i, x in enumerate(order)]

#last join together, sorting and last remove helper column
df = pd.concat(L).sort_values(['group','g'])
```

Comment: concatenate combines both the dataframe. But I need a rule to write. For example, I need to check whether the dataframe is empty, when it is empty the I have to select different dataframe .

Comment: hmm, if use `dfs = [x.ffill() for x in dfs]` it not working?

Comment: @i1100362 - So empty values in `group` are not `NaN`s ? It is something different?

Comment: Actually it works but not as I required. I have dtaframe : `df1,df2,df3,df4,df5` and now I wanna write data from `df2 and df5` should fill in alternate way and when `df2 or df5` is empty take values from`df1`then `df3` and last `df4`

Comment: @i1100362 - So do you think `emty` DataFrame are `df2, df5` ? Or emty groups? Because if empty DataFrame, `pd.concat(dfs)` remove empty DataFrames

Comment: nope. what I mentioned is its showing as same as  `group ordercode  quantity
0    0.0         A         1
1    NaN         B         3
2    1.0         C         1
3    NaN         E         2
4    NaN         D         1`

Comment: @i1100362 - Is possible edit question? Because bad format of data in comments. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181341/discussion-between-i1100362-and-jezrael).